# doctrine/orm upgrade 2.4 to 2.5

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I try to upgrade my doctrine/orm from 2.4.8 to 2.5.3

Here a part of my composer.json :

```
"require": {
    "symfony/symfony": "~2.7, <2.8",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.5",
    "doctrine/dbal": "~2.5",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.6",
    "doctrine/common": "~2.5", 
    ...
}
```

And I got the following Exception :

```
Fatal error: Class 'Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\BasicEntityPersister' not found in /var/www/mywebsite/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php on line 2983
```

The problem is, if I check the `UnitOfWork.php` file, the use statment is there...

If I change to

```
"require": {
    "symfony/symfony": "~2.7, <2.8",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,<2.5",
    "doctrine/dbal": "~2.5",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.6",
    "doctrine/common": "~2.5", 
    ...
}
```

It's work well

[image]

Comment: In `doctrine/orm` there is nothing like that happening in line 2983. Do you have some kind of Opcode cache that must be cleared?

Comment: You should clear cache and then recheck.

Comment: It was that, simply... Thank you both